# Relaciones entre entidades en Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Tengo las entidades Ubicación y Edificio, cuya relación es uno a muchos, un Edificio está en una Ubicación (ciudad, estado), y en una Ubicación pueden haber varios Edificios.

Ubicación (Location):

```
namespace dotnet_api.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid loc_id {get; set;}
        public string loc_type {get; set;}
        public string loc_name {get; set;}

        [ForeignKey("Location")]
        public Guid? loc_id_fk {get; set;}
        public List<Location>? locations {get; set;}

        [ForeignKey("Building")]
        public Guid? fk_bui_id {get; set;}
        public List<Building>? buildings {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Departamento:

```
namespace dotnet_api.Models
{
    public class Building
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid bui_id {get; set;}
        public string bui_name {get; set;}
        public string bui_description {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("Location")]
        public Guid loc_id {get; set;}    
        public Location location {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es, cada vez que deseo instanciar un nuevo objeto de la clase Location (ubicacion), tengo que pasarle como argumento una lista de objetos de tipo departamento, y viceversa?

En una llamada a la API para hacer post de location, si necesito pasarle null en Building, cómo se hace en ese caso?

Comment: Piensa que son objetos y los puedes instanciar de todas las maneras posibles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿ Cada vez que deseo instanciar un nuevo objeto de la clase Location
> (ubicacion), tengo que pasarle como argumento una lista de objetos de
> tipo departamento, y viceversa?

Respuesta corta: No, no es obligatorio

**1) Desde el punto de vista de C#**

Una propiedad de un objeto debe instanciarse obligatoriamente cuando está en el constructor, y aun así una lista puede pasarse como null.

Es decir la única forma que es obligatorio, es que tu clase fuera así:

```
public class Location {
  public List<Building>? buildings {get; set;}
  public Location(List<Building>? buildings){
     this.buildings = building;
  }

 //etc
```

Y que por supuesto, que no hubiera otro constructor (ej: un constructor sin argumentos)

**2) Desde el punto de vista de Entity Framework (EF) y la base de datos.**

Las clases para EF, en general, no tienen constructor. Así que no hay problema por este lado.

Para operaciones CRUD, tampoco es necesario.

- Para Listar: Si colocas un [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-6.0), las propiedades de navegación vienen con los datos relacionados
- Para Borrar no es necesario, solo necesitas la Id
- Para Crear y editar: No es obligatorio, pero muchas veces se incluye. Porque quieres Editar/crear todo de un golpe. Pasas la clase padre entera incluyendo las tablas hijas, para una modificación masiva de toda la entidad

Esto es especialmente claro para relaciones 1 es a muchos, ¿Pero qué pasa en muchos es a 1? Es decir ¿para guardar un objeto `Building` se necesita `Location`?

Tampoco se necesita, solo se necesita la propiedad que actúa de FK es decir `loc_id`

> En una llamada a la API para hacer post de location, si necesito
> pasarle null en Building, cómo se hace en ese caso?

Puedes poner null, o simplemente no ponerlo.

---

Otras cosas:

En tu clase Location, esto sobra

```
[ForeignKey("Building")]
public Guid? fk_bui_id {get; set;}
```

Con esto haces una relación 1 a 1

También te recomiendo leer https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions ahí explican pequeñas reglas para dar nombre a las propiedades. Son pocas pero utilices

Comment: Muchas gracias :)